# htaccess for my subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use `mod_rewrite` on my sub domain:

```
ads.domain.org/details.php
```

I need to rewrite it to:

```
ads.domain.org/something.html
```

I can do this in main domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something\.html$ /details.php?id=1 [L]
```

But I cant do it on sub domain.

Comment: Is your sub domain on a different folder or on the same root folder of your main domain?

Comment: my subdomain on folder on main domain
'www.domain.org/subdomainfolder'

Comment: Then your rule needs to be on an .htaccess inside the subdomainfolder

Comment: [Kindly mark mahatmanich as the right answer then as he had it pointed out. See here how to check his answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the subdomain maps to a different host directory, thus you also need to add the .htaccess to that directory for it to work, also you may need to activate mod_rewrite on that directory maybe even on your virtual host level, just some pointers...

Answer (score 0):

Add a `RewriteCond` to check HOST value:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ads\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^something\.html$ /details.php?id=1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: it's redirect me to index.php

Comment: As you can see there is no `index.php` in my code above. Post your complete .htaccess for further investigation.